# Android Studio : Error: cannot find symbol class DBClass

Tags: android, sqlite, mobile

```
   private TextView tv2;
   private TextView tv3;
   private DBClass dbClass;
```

Ive been declare the DBClass but in the end it said

error: cannot find symbol class DBClass

which library i should import or how im gonna solve this problem?

Comment: you should visit the http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html
java.lang.Object
   ↳ android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable
     ↳ android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase

Answer (score 0):

Your DBClass.java file can be like this-

```
public class DBClass extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int database_version = 1;
    private static final String database_name = "test.db";

    public Databaseconnector(Context context) {
        super(context, database_name, null, database_version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("<create tablle statement>");
    }

    // method used if want to upgrade DB means version.
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Why you posted answer? How did you know `DBClass` ? At least post comment `where is code?` By giving answer you just encourage op to ask such a questions in future.

Comment: @M D, Thanks for indicating the mistake , I will keep in mind for the future answers.